# SocketIO + Pyinstaller + SSL only does polling

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, socket.io, pyinstaller

I have created a python application that uses socketIO-client from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client)

The app connects to a SocketIO server and communication goes as expected, through websockets, when running it through PyCharm IDE or through the terminal using the command `python myapp.py`. 
However when running the compiled version created by Pyinstaller over SSL, it only talks over the polling transport. Connecting without SSL does connect through websockets even with the compiled version.

I am currently developing on OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.4).

Pyinstaller version 3.0

Python 2.7.10

Running this command to create the executable:

```
pyinstaller -p myapp/ --onefile myapp/myapp.py
```

Any idea what could be causing this behavior? Any guesses?

Thank you.